# Delete a row in Google Sheets when a date has passed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-comparison

I have a spreadsheet that I would like to autosort based on date, delete duplicate rows, and delete rows if the date listed has passed. I have the autosort and deleting duplicates, I just need help with deleting rows based on the date. It will delete all rows except row # 2, regardless of date.

So far I have:

```
function deleteRow1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date();
    var sheetDate = new Date(row);
    var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'EST-0500', 'MM:dd:yyyy')
    var SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate, 'EST-0500', 'MM:dd:yyyy')
    if (Sdate > SsheetDate) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 2) 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing dates as `String`s and not as `Date`s? Note that `"a" < "b"` and `"10" < "2"` are both `true`... Also note that your script skips checking a row for each row it deletes.

Comment: What changes would you recommend? I don't think I quite follow...

Comment: I think what @tehhowch is driving at is to get rid of the lines var sdate and var sSheetDate, then compare if date>sDate (maybe first giving a little thought to that today now is later than today at midnight). At the very least I would think you want the YYYY before the mmdd. Also it feels safer to go from the end row up to the beginning row so the world is not shifting underneath you.

Answer (score 0):

So here is about what it could look like, I think. I changed as little as I could about your routine, focusing on the parts that seemed like they were troubling.

In particular, dates are compared to dates, with times removed/equated. Also, it bothered me to repeatedly construct today, so I took that outside the loop.

Also, I worked from the bottom up to make sure deletions did not affect which row to consider next.

```
    function deleteRow1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  for (i = data.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    var row = data[i];
    var sheetDate = new Date(row);
    sheetDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if (today > sheetDate) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 2) 
    }
  }


}
```

It might be a nice touch to change i+2 to startRow+i.

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks @tehhowch for the design. Please hit the check mark to accept the answer if you are satisfied.